# Unable to Run Appium Test both emulator and real mobile devices

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I have basic appium automation test which just  launches the app on mobile device and has to perform some operations.
The same code is running on others machine while I am facing issues running it.

I am getting this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new
>   remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original
>   error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error:
>   'Command '/Users/xyz/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s
>   2d5c1222 shell pm clear com.android.calculator2' exited with code 1';
>   Stderr: 'Error: java.lang.SecurityException: adb clearing user data is
>   forbidden.'; Code: '1' Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision:
>   'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host:
>   'xyz.local', ip: 'xxxx:x:x:x:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%en0', os.name: 'Mac
>   OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version:
>   '11.0.3' Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver

Other details:

- appium version: 1.14.2
- node:12.6
- adb: 1.0.41

Unable to resolve the error.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID,udid);
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.calculator2");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".Calculator");
AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> appiumDriver = new AppiumDriver<>(new URL(APPIUM_SERVER_URL.replace("port", appiumPort)), capabilities);
```

Comment: perhaps the action you want to do with adb is not supported now in the given version of device!!

Comment: okay! so I tried using different virtual devices and apparently it worked on some of them! but then how to figure out exactly what's the problem!

Comment: Run `adb -s 2d5c1222 shell pm clear com.android.calculator2'` from the command line and check what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `appActivity` capability needs to be changed. Usually `appActivity` is formatted with the `appPackage` name at the beginning, followed by activity name.

So instead of:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".Calculator");
```

Try:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
```

If the appActivity is still causing issues, you might need to pull the correct data using [this guide](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/).